# accessing ctx object in a function used in fixture.before or fixture.after hook

Tags: testcafe

is it possible to access the `ctx` object in a function that's meant to be used in a fixture.before or fixture.after hook?

here's a snippet of code that i've tried on my side:

**util.js**

```
export function testCtxObject() {
    ctx.test = '123'
}
```

**test.js**

```
import { testCtxObject } from 'util';

fixture('Access ctx object in fixture hooks')
    .before(async (ctx) => {
        testCtxObject();
    });

...
```

when i run a test in `test.js`, i end up getting this error:

```
1) - Error in fixture.before hook -
    Cannot implicitly resolve the test run in the context of which the test controller
    action should be executed. Use test function's 't' argument instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just send it as a function argument.

Comment: is it possible to pass the context object in and modify it? e.g., if i have a `ctx.prop` property, will a function be able to update its value?

Comment: yes, if you just pass the `ctx` object to the function as an argument